# Input type number max value not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input type number element with a min and max values. Preventing the default function I have customized it to use the with separate inputs.

I don't know how can we trigger the max value from the input element which contains min and max attributes. Though i give max range the plus crosses the value.

```js
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
    $(this).prev('input').attr('value', val + 1);
});

$('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    if (val !== 0) {
        $(this).next('input').attr('value', val - 1);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  margin: 40px;
}

.minus,
.plus {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=number].quantity::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
   -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}

.quantity {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-block">
    <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" value="1" class="quantity" size="4" min="1" max="5"/>
    <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Comment: There is an idiot called @JohnSlegers editing all posts and answers, maybe to grow badges. I rollback all editions.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude : I've just been improving readability, indentation and spacing of this and various other questions. Why is that a bad thing? How does that make me an idiot, exactly?! And no, I'm not doing this for "badges"... I guess you could call me a "readability Nazi" (lacking a better term for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `max` attribute and then use it in a condition.:

```js
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
    var max = parseInt($(this).prev('input').attr('max'));
    if(val < max) {
      $(this).prev('input').attr('value', val + 1);
    }
});

$('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    if (val !== 0) {
        $(this).next('input').attr('value', val - 1);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  margin: 40px;
}

.minus,
.plus {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=number].quantity::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
   -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}

.quantity {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-block">
    <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" value="1" class="quantity" size="4" min="1" max="5"/>
    <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is independent to HTML5 validation. So you can get the max and min value from jquery and set the max and min value to the js. Like :

```
 $('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
    var max = parseInt($(this).prev('input').attr('max'));
    if(val == max) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).prev('input').val(val + 1);

});

 $('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    var min = $(this).prev('input').attr("min");
   if (val == min) {
      return;
   }
    $(this).next('input').val(val - 1);

 });

 // to prevent when user directly type to the textbox

 $(".quantity").keydown(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      var min = $(this).attr("min");
      var max = $(this).attr("max");
      if(val > max || val < min){
          $(this).val("");
          return false;    
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had to put an if condition,

```js
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
     if (val < $(this).prev('input').attr('max'))
       {
    $(this).prev('input').attr('value', val + 1);
         }
});

$('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    if (val !== 0) {
        $(this).next('input').attr('value', val - 1);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  margin: 40px;
}

.minus, .plus {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=number].quantity::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
   -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}

.quantity {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-block">
    <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" value="1" class="quantity" size="4" min="1" max="5"/>
    <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `min/max` attributes of `input[type=number]` is working but only with arrow keys, for `+/-` button clicks it would be better to have some conditions as suggested below:

```js
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
  if (val != $(this).prev('input').attr('max')) { // check the value against max attribute
    $(this).prev('input').attr('value', val + 1);
  }
});

$('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
  if (val != $(this).next('input').attr('min')) {// check the value against min attribute
    $(this).next('input').attr('value', val - 1);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 40px;
}
.minus,
.plus {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=number].quantity::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.quantity {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-block">
  <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="quantity" min="1" max="5" />
  <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a problem I had to solve when I was studying - (make two buttons that increment or decrement a value and when the number reaches the min value - reset it to the max and vice versa). I rejigged it a bit to take into account your min / max values. Not saying its necessarily good - but it was an interesting problem for a learning programmer.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = "button" value = "-1"></input>
        <input type = "text" value = "1" id="counter"  min="0" max="5"></input>
        <input type = "button" value = "+1"></input>

        <script>
            $(":button").click(function() {
                var result = parseFloat($("#counter").val())+parseFloat(($(this).val()));
                if(result>$("#counter").attr('max')){result=1}else{if(result==$("#counter").attr('min')){result=5}};
                $('#counter').val(result);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```